# Highlight (Active) menu post title in a category.php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

This is the website i´m working on: http://canal.es/wordpress/

The problem I have is that, if you go, to "**Pasteleria dulce**" (which is a category.php file) it shows a left sidebar with the active title of the category, it shows a post on the center and it shows below the image a list of the post of the same category.

I haven´t find a solution to highlight the post title that opens automatically when I enter to the category. This is the code i´m using on the category.php file:

```
    <!--  Highlight menu from current category -->
    <?php
        if (is_category()) {
            $this_category = get_category($cat);
            }
        if($this_category->category_parent)
            $this_category = wp_list_categories('orderby=id&title_li=&child_of='.$this_category->category_parent."&echo=0"); else
            $this_category = wp_list_categories('orderby=id&title_li=&child_of='.$this_category->cat_ID."&echo=0");
        if ($this_category) { ?>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <?php echo $this_category; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php } ?>



    <div class="producto_column">           
       <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <div class="producto_image">
                <img src="<?php the_field('imagen_producto'); ?>" alt=""/>
            </div>

                <div class="share_item">
                    <a class="minimal" id="premium">
                        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/images/share.png" alt="share">
                    </a>
                    <a class="maillink" href="http://canal.local/?page_id=220">
                        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/images/email.png" alt="email">
                    </a>
                </div>

            <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

    <!--  Post list from current category -->
    <ul id="submenu_productos" class="clearfix">
        <?php
            $IDOutsideLoop = $post->ID;
            while( have_posts() ) {
                the_post();
                foreach( ( get_the_category() ) as $category )
                    $my_query = new WP_Query('category_name=' . $category->category_nicename . '&orderby=title&order=asc&showposts=100');
                if( $my_query ) {
                    while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
                        $my_query->the_post(); ?>
                <li<?php print ( is_single() && $IDOutsideLoop == $post->ID ) ? ' class="test"' : ''; ?>>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> |
                </li>
        <?php
                }
            }
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
```

How can I make active the current post title that appears when I open the category page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this solution:

```
<ul>

    <?php
        $lastposts = get_posts('numberposts=5&orderby=rand&cat=-52');
        foreach($lastposts as $post) :
        setup_postdata($post); ?>

        <li<?php if ( $post->ID == $wp_query->post->ID ) { echo ' class="current"'; } else {} ?>>

            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

        </li>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

</ul>
```

Comment: It doesn´t seem to work. thank you anyway. It looks like this target the path wich is the current category path, not the path of the post...

Comment: Try new one! This may hepl's you

Comment: hehe no, now this one shows post from all categories randomly... look at the site, it doesn´t highlight anything

Comment: You try all code? This is exmple! Try this part <?php if ( $post->ID == $wp_query->post->ID ) { echo ' class="current"'; } else {} ?>

Comment: yeah it worked man!! I just have to add the line you add in the last comment! thank you very much!

Comment: It's my pleasure! If any question skype my skype radik.chernysov